# Creating a sub-menu from initial menu python notebook app

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, menu

I am making a notebook application while studying inheritance and class-building, and I would like to know if there is a better way of creating a second menu from the first menu (no GUI yet, just command line). We start in the first menu, and inputting "3" brings us to another menu. This second menu is a class, a near-duplicate of the first, the only differences being the method functionality/names. I wonder if I can just make this second menu a child of the original menu-class so I avoid code duplication?

Here is the code for the first menu, which the second menu-class duplicates:

```
"""First menu"""

class Start:

    def __init__(self):
        self.page = Page()
        self.choices = {
            "1": self.write,
            "2": self.erase,
            "3": self.show,
            "4": self.quit,
    }

    def display_menu(self):
        """print some options for the user to select"""
    
    def run(self):
        """Keep display menu running"""
        while True:
            self.display_menu()

    def show(self):
        """call the second menu, which is a class duplicating
        the code of this first menu class"""
        SecondMenu().run_menu()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Start().run()
```

To go from the second menu back to the first, the back method in the second menu calls the first menu

```
"""Second Menu"""

class SecondMenu:
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def back(self):
        Start().run()
```

Thanks in advance. Let me know if more clarification is required, I am new to oop principles.

Comment: If you are starting with OOP, certain patterns like App().run() can make you build things like a single big object with everything inside, while you should try to partition your system in several small and more focused parts (classes/objects)  that colaborate with each other to do what is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the infinite loop to your main program, you can think of instantiating and presenting to the user a new (or existing) menu in every iteration, until he chooses `Q(uit)` from the main menu.

Then you can define a base class `Menu` with the basics only. After that you can think in a `MainMenu` sub-class, and whatever more menus you need.

The menus do not need to interact with the user, but with your program. Your program is basically a loop asking for a menu option from the user.

This isolation can be useful if you think of other ways to interact with a user or other system, and you still want to re-use these menus.

Having the menus running everything from themselves, while possible, looks a bit like menu overdesign.

You may also like the `cmd` module from the standard library. It is also object-oriented. You'll have to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) and follow by it's rules though. You'll find examples there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take a bit of time to try and do what you have suggested.